# Returning an array from a method with user input in java

Tags: java

I'm getting an illegal start of expression error next to `public static double getAverage (double average) {`

I'm also getting an error stating "Variable average is not used" next to `double average = sum /(double) arr.length;`

I've been working it for a while, I'm not sure what to do anymore.
Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

  public static void main(String [] args){                    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers you want to display: ");

    int n=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter array values: ");

    int arr [] = new int[n];
    int sum=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = input.nextInt();
      sum+=arr[i];
      double average = sum / (double) arr.length;

      public static double getAverage(double average){     
        System.out.println("Average value of array: " + average);
        {
          return average; 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @codeguru: It would have been better not to have fixed the original post's indentation since that was one part of problems that contributed to the overall problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a method within a method, declaring the `getAverage(...)` method inside of the `main(...)` method -- and Java doesn't allow this. End your main method with a closing curly brace and create your next method outside of the main method. Please read up on how to create methods in your text book or [the Java Tutorials, methods section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) as it will all be explained there.

Also you want to format your code better using a correct, consistent and uniform indentation style. Doing this will prevent you from making this same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After removing all the tab characters and replacing them with spaces, hopefully you can see that the `getAverage()` method is being declared inside of `main()`. This is not allowed. You need to declare methods within a class, but not within other methods. Once you fix the function declaration, we can work from there.